# .on() a jQuery event after an .off()

Tags: jquery

I have a `.on('click','td', function(){})` event.
I turn it `.off('click','td')`. I now would like to `.on()` the same event again. 
I tried some combinations of `.on()` and it did not work. Could be done by assigning it to a variable, not sure how to do that though.

Comment: [I can't replicate this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/UcHj9/)

Comment: Do I have to define the entire function again? I want to .on() an event that I have defined before. could be done by assigning it to a variable, not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the event handler function in a variable, and use it like this:

```
var handler = function(e){
    //code here
}

//on
$('#myselector').on('click', handler);

//off
//Try this, this will only turn 'handler' off
$('#myselector').off('click', handler);

//If the above doesn't work, then try this
//This will turn off all your other click handlers for the same element,
//if for some reason turning off a particular handler doesn't work!
$('#myselector').off('click');

//on again
$('#myselector').on('click', handler);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that clicking the TD try this:
first having your td a class to tell if it is on or off. By default TD will have td-off class, like this

```
<td class="td-off">
```

then set your an event changing the class.

```
.on('click','td',function(){

  if($(this).hasClass('td-off')){
    $(this).removeClass('td-off');
    $(this).addClass('td-on');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('td-on');
    $(this).addClass('td-off');
  }

});
```

then finally set the event of your on or off

```
$('.td-on').click(function(){
    //Your event on
});

$('.td-off').click(function(){
   //Your event off
});
```

It may not be the best answer but I hope you get the idea

Comment: dont know why i didnot think about it. Let me give it a try, should work.